# Appending and removing shorthand in python

Tags: python

I notice that in python you can append to a list with `+=` do this:

```
s = ['a', 'b', 'c']
s += 'd'
# s = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Which is the same as doing `s.append('d')`. But there is not an equivalent for s.remove('a'):

```
s -= 'a'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'list' and 'str'
```

So what is happening when you use `+=`?

Comment: Try with `'de'`, `+=` is not same as `.append()` it is equivalent to `.extend()` in case of list.

Comment: Also, the opposite of `append()` is `pop()`, not `remove()`. The latter does a search starting from the beginning of the array and could be a costly operation on long arrays.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`+=` on a `list` is *not* the same as doing `s.append`. It's the same as doing `s.extend`. It only happens to look the same in this case because a string is a sequence of characters, so a one-character string is a sequence of itself. In general, it's very different. Try it with numbers, or 3-character strings.

---

Anyway, "what is happening when you use `+=`" goes like this:

First, the statement `a += b` looks up the method `a.__iadd__`. If it exists (as it usually does on objects that can be mutated in-place, like `list`), it's transformed into this code:

```
a = a.__iadd__(b)
```

Otherwise (as with immutable objects, like `int`), it's transformed (loosely speaking) into:

```
a = a + b
```

`list.__iadd__` exists. In CPython, of course, it's implemented in C, but the equivalent Python code is pretty trivial:

```
def __iadd__(self, other):
    self.extend(other)
    return self
```

That `extend` method is equivalent to this:

```
def self.extend(self, iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        self.append(element)
```

So, your `s += 'd'` effectively does this:

```
for char in 'd': # this loops once, with `char` being `'d'`
    s.append(char)
s = s
```

---

Obviously under the covers a lot of things are optimized; `extend` doesn't have to look up the `append` method dynamically or call it in a loop (possibly expanding the list's storage multiple times), it just has to have the same visible effect as if it had done so.

---

For more on how this works, see the following sections of the documentation:

- [Emulating numeric types](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types) explains exactly how `a += b` is interpreted.
- [Emulating container types](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types) explains how this specifically applies to containers.
- [Sequence Types — `list`, `tuple`, `range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range) explains what `list.__iadd__`, `list.extend`, and `list.append` all do.
- [`collections.abc.MutableSequence`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes) shows what operations mutable sequences in general are expected to support.
- [Augmented assignment statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements) explains the details on how `+=` is parsed (note that it's not an operator in Python, unlike many other languages, but rather a special kind of thing that can only appear in statements, not expressions).